# Cannot invoke getText() on the array type String[]

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android. I have an error in my java code:

> Cannot invoke getText on the array type string.

I put gender in a spinner and I declared it in an array.

Error is on this line

```
String gendert=gender.getText().toString();
```

Comment: What type is `gender`?

Comment: You will increase your chance for an answer if you improve your question: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @MikeB string array type

Comment: So `String[] gender`?

Comment: @MikeB  ArrayList<String> items=new ArrayList<String>();
  String[] gender =  {"--Select--","Male","Female"};

Comment: You'll want to work with the actual `Spinner` object that the array backs instead of the array itself.

Comment: @MikeB :yes string[] gender

Comment: @mikeB :Can you help me how it will be? code?

Answer (score 1):

You should get a value from gender `Spinner` in a following way:

```
String gendert = gender.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

**EDIT** How to set values in `Spinner` properly for `String` values:

```
String[] myArray = {"Male", "Female"};
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myArray);
gender.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: same error is remaining.Cannot invoke getSelectedItem() on the array type String[]

Comment: @NeenuJose That is probably because you are still invoking `getSelectedItem()` on the `String[]` object, while you should invoke it on the actual `Spinner` object that is using the `String[]` for its options.

Comment: @Neenu Jose please check my edit

Comment: error on this line :gender.setAdapter(MyAdapter);errors are  Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
 - Syntax error on token ")", . expected
 - Syntax error on token "MyAdapter", VariableDeclaratorId expected after 
  this token

Comment: @nikis , i have still the above error, whether we have to initialize the gender with any type